# Looping nested dictionaries with if statements Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have got a number of inner dictionaries, my logic is off somewhat as my output is close to what I want to accomplish but not quite there yet.  I would like to concatenate the values of two variables from inner dictionaries.

While in the loops my variables print correctly, but when I use another variable to concatenate both, I receive only a few values.  This data is coming from a JSON structure.

Code:

```
try:
    k_bulky_count = ' '
    for sr in BulkyItem:
            for bulkycount in BulkyItem['BulkyItem']:
                            countBulky =  bulkycount['BulkyItemCount']
                            if k_bulky_count != countBulky:
                                k_bulky_count =  countBulky
                                print k_bulky_count
except:
    print "data"

try:
    k_bulky_item = ''
    for sr in BulkyItem:
        for bulkyitem in BulkyItem['BulkyItem']:
            itemBulky =  bulkyitem['BulkyItemType']
            if k_bulky_item != itemBulky:
                    k_bulky_item = itemBulky
                    BulkyItemInfo += '{0}, {1} '.format (k_bulky_count, k_bulky_item)
                    print BulkyItemInfo
except:
    print ("No Bulky Info")
```

Output for BulkyItemInfo:

```
 1, Carpet 
 1, Carpet 1, Chair 
 1, Carpet 1, Chair 1, Desk 
 1, Carpet 1, Chair 1, Desk 1, Wood Bundles 
 1, Carpet 1, Chair 1, Desk 1, Wood Bundles 1, Other 
 1, Bookcase 
 1, Bicycle 
 2, Carpet 
 2, Carpet 2, Chair 
 2, Carpet 2, Chair 2, Headboard 
 1, Bicycle 
 1, Bicycle 1, Bird Cage (Plastic) 
 1, Bicycle 1, Bird Cage (Plastic) 1, Blinds 
 1, Bicycle 1, Bird Cage (Plastic) 1, Blinds 1, Bookcase 
 1, Bicycle 1, Bird Cage (Plastic) 1, Blinds 1, Bookcase 1, Dresser 
 1, Bicycle 1, Bird Cage (Plastic) 1, Blinds 1, Bookcase 1, Dresser 1, Entertainment Center 
 1, Bookcase 
 1, Bookcase 1, Desk 
 1, Bookcase 1, Desk 1, Shelf
```

Output for Quantity and Type when printed in respective loops

```
1
File Cabinet (Wood)
1
Carpet
Chair
Desk
Wood Bundles
Other
1
Bookcase
1
Bicycle
5
6
2
Carpet
Chair
Headboard
```

Json Example:

```
{
    "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
        "BulkyItem": [
            {
                "BulkyItemCount": "5",
                "BulkyItemType": "Carpet",
                "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                "Type": "Bulky Items",
                "SpecialRule": "Y",
                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                "LastUpdatedBy": "52299",
                "DriverFirstName": "",
                "DriverLastName": "",
                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                "TruckNo": "",
                "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                "PurposeofSR": "",
                "Name": "061720151151242471"
            },
            {
                "BulkyItemCount": "6",
                "BulkyItemType": "Chair",
                "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                "Type": "Bulky Items",
                "SpecialRule": "",
                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                "LastUpdatedBy": "52299",
                "DriverFirstName": "",
                "DriverLastName": "",
                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                "TruckNo": "",
                "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                "PurposeofSR": "",
                "Name": "061720151151242472"
            },
            {
                "BulkyItemCount": "2",
                "BulkyItemType": "Headboard",
                "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                "Type": "Bulky Items",
                "SpecialRule": "Y",
                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                "LastUpdatedBy": "52299",
                "DriverFirstName": "",
                "DriverLastName": "",
                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                "TruckNo": "",
                "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                "PurposeofSR": "",
                "Name": "061720151151242483"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Desired output from above json

```
5, Carpet, 6, Chair, 2 Headboard
```

Comment: Why not just use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module of the standard library?

Comment: I think you're completely misunderstanding this.

Comment: Reason might be you do not state clearly what you want to achieve or what your problem is. So, just enlighten me.

Comment: The desired output is shown in the question, from the JSON above, I would like to loop and have a formatted string.   I am able to iterate the json, but my logic is incorrect in the loop.   I am consuming this json from a web-service, and am already using the json module.

Comment: So the information is quite useless. Your question is still not clear what you want to achieve. Just remember _you_ are deep into that matter, _we_ are not. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I do not understand what's not clear, I have provided a JSON and desired output from the said JSON, in addition to functional code which references the json and the output and my desired output...what needs to be scaled back in order for you to better understand this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you need but this code gives the desired output from the given json string:

```
import json

jsonstr = '''
{
    "ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
        "BulkyItem": [
            {
                "BulkyItemCount": "5",
                "BulkyItemType": "Carpet",
                "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                "Type": "Bulky Items",
                "SpecialRule": "Y",
                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                "LastUpdatedBy": "52299",
                "DriverFirstName": "",
                "DriverLastName": "",
                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                "TruckNo": "",
                "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                "PurposeofSR": "",
                "Name": "061720151151242471"
            },
            {
                "BulkyItemCount": "6",
                "BulkyItemType": "Chair",
                "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                "Type": "Bulky Items",
                "SpecialRule": "",
                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                "LastUpdatedBy": "52299",
                "DriverFirstName": "",
                "DriverLastName": "",
                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                "TruckNo": "",
                "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                "PurposeofSR": "",
                "Name": "061720151151242472"
            },
            {
                "BulkyItemCount": "2",
                "BulkyItemType": "Headboard",
                "CollectionLocation": "Curb",
                "IllegallyDumped": "N",
                "OtherBulkyItem": "",
                "Type": "Bulky Items",
                "SpecialRule": "Y",
                "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
                "MobileHomeSpace": "",
                "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "",
                "LastUpdatedBy": "52299",
                "DriverFirstName": "",
                "DriverLastName": "",
                "ServiceDateRendered": "",
                "TruckNo": "",
                "ActiveStatus": "Y",
                "IllegalBulkyItemType": "",
                "PurposeofSR": "",
                "Name": "061720151151242483"
            }
        ]
    }
}
'''

dic = json.loads(jsonstr)

astr = ""
for listofbulkyitems in dic.itervalues():
    for bulkyitems in listofbulkyitems.itervalues():
        for bulkyitem in bulkyitems:
            if astr:
                astr += ", "     ## The string should not start by a comma but all the following items should be preceded by a comma
            astr += bulkyitem['BulkyItemCount']+", "+bulkyitem['BulkyItemType']
print astr
## prints '5, Carpet, 6, Chair, 2, Headboard'
```

Note that I chose to store everything in a string before printing it. It is not necessary but it is a straightforward way to get the desired output.